# configuration management tool to automate the property files

Tags: configuration-files

Any configuration management tool in the market to automate the property file for the different environments, lets say i have one complete configuration files with key and values but for the other environments the values will differ so am just trying to look out if this could be done easily like template or csv or any other valuable approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Sparrow6](https://github.com/melezhik/Sparrow6) automation DSL to populate configuration files using embedded [templater](https://github.com/melezhik/Sparrow6/blob/master/documentation/dsl.md#templates). You can go even further and utilize [Tomtit](https://github.com/melezhik/Tomtit) task runner that integrates with Sparrow6 and provides [environments](https://github.com/melezhik/Tomtit/blob/master/README.md#environments) feature for these very types of tasks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try https://microconfig.io
It is designed to solve the configuration problem you’re describing. 
It supports properties and yaml format.